# Is it a good UX practice to have more than two popups?

Tags: overlay

Once I select search icon, the pop up appears as shown in the image. Results are displayed in the same popup. But the problem is once I select one of the Pins (say Pin 1) a pop up appears with additional information as shown in image 2 on first popup.

So is it good UX practice to have two popups? Or should I close the first popup once the user selects a pin and just keep second popup?

[image]

Comment: You can probably try like a in place popover.

Comment: The real problem lies in the fact that the foreground modal always needs to be smaller than the one in the background—if the opacity is set at 1.

Comment: Absolutely NO !

Answer (score 2):

**More than one pop up is always overwhelming**,I usually try to avoid it,instead what I would try is :

- The info shown on both popus is more or less similar so we can try to
  accomodate that in a single screen.
- The comment section could be a simple link that when clicked just
  pushes the options below to make space for typing your comment.
- or as you suggested,if you are absolutely sure about the pin you are
  looking for,it makes sense to close the first popup.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an accordion pattern for this area Divi, you can collapse the information in a header and have the entire details area and comments in the body. I have to agree with Nirav, you should try to avoid multiple pop-up windows at all cost, they are heavy to work with and usually lose context easily. Also I hope you don't have content behind that search if you are planning on showing a preview of the search area selection. Here is my view of it:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtKkB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Save should be done on blur on the comment field. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the other action buttons/links on previous pop-up is not useful for latest popup, they need to be disabled.

One way to solve this is to apply a fullscreen transparent background overlay to cover the previous pop up to prevent mis-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to add the "Comments" text input (as in your example)

I strongly recommend to use inline editing (pressing the pin / a 'modify' link on the pin...)
So when activated, the 'comments' input appears directly inline, with its associated save button.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVE2oM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This way you will avoid having 2 popup, which is not as bad as it sounds but always feels clumsy for the users.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on what exactly the ui you are designing and what platform is it on. is it a web site, or a web application or a mobile/tablet application? If it's a desktop application, they can be 'windows' instead of popups. having more than 2 windows is fine.